# C++ most frequent element in map

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

I made a program that takes data from file, puts it into vector and then checks for most frequent element in the vector. (using map)
The problem is when I have same number of elements in the data (two Element1, two Element2, one Element3). It returns Element1 and I need it to pass the information that there is "no most frequent element".
My code looks like:

```
using namespace std;

bool comp(const pair<string, unsigned long> &pair1,
        const pair<string, unsigned long> &pair2) {
    return pair1.second < pair2.second;
}

string Odczyt::tokenizer() {

    inFile.open("baza.txt");

    while (!inFile.eof()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            inFile >> row1[i] >> row2[i] >> row3[i] >> row4[i];
        }
    }

    sVector1.assign(row1, row1 + 3);

    string w1 = most_occurred(sVector1);

    return w1;

}

string Odczyt::most_occurred(vector<string> &vec) {

    map<string, unsigned long> str_map1;

    for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end();
            ++it) {
        ++str_map1[*it];
    }

    return max_element(str_map1.begin(), str_map1.end(), comp)->first;
}
```

Comment: What should your logic for breaking ties be? Do you just return nothing or all ties?

Comment: I just need most frequent element if there is any or information that there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

string most_occurred(vector<string> &vec) {
    map<string, unsigned long> str_map1;
    std::string max_element = "";
    int max_count = 0;

    typedef vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
    iter end = vec.end();

    for (iter it = vec.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
        int count = ++str_map1[*it];
        if(count == max_count) max_element = "no max found";
        if(count >  max_count) {
            max_count = count;
            max_element = *it;
        }
    }

    return max_element;
}

int main() {
    std::string arr1[5] = {"aa" , "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"}; // no max found
    std::string arr2[5] = {"aa" , "aa", "cc", "dd", "ee"};// aa
    std::string arr3[5] = {"aa" , "aa", "cc", "cc", "ee"}; // no max found
    std::vector<std::string> input1(arr1, arr1+5);
    std::vector<std::string> input2(arr2, arr2+5);
    std::vector<std::string> input3(arr3, arr3+5);
    std::cout << most_occurred(input1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << most_occurred(input2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << most_occurred(input3) << std::endl;
}
```

the result is:

```
no max found
aa
no max found
```

---

The following test resulted in `no max found`.

```
int main() {
    std::string arr1[24] = {"Element1", "Element2", "Element33", "1",
    "Element1", "Element2", "Element33", "2", "Element11", "Element2",
    "Element33", "2", "Element11" "Element21" "Element31", "2", "Element11",
    "Element21", "Element31", "1", "Element12", "Element21", "Element31",
    "1"}; // no max found
    std::vector<std::string> input1(arr1, arr1+24);
    std::cout << most_occurred(input1) << std::endl;
}
```

If the above code returns std::string("") then there was no max element, else it will return the max.

Comment: I've been playing withe the answer you gave me for last few minutes. It doesn't enter        if(count == max_count) max_element = ""; part. It still finds most frequent element.                             My test data file looks like: Element1 Element2 Element33 1
Element1 Element2 Element33 2
Element11 Element2 Element33 2
Element11 Element21 Element31 2
Element11 Element21 Element31 1
Element12 Element21 Element31 1

Comment: @user2336450 I tested the code above and it worked as I would expect it to.

Comment: @user2336450 I just tested your input and I got that no results max was found. Are you sure your parsing the file correctly?

Comment: I just checked with your code and manual array. It has to be something with parsing from file. I'll just look at it all one by one. Thank you for help.

Comment: It was one awful segmentation fault error. Fixed it and it's working. Thanks for help again.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable which stores the number of times you have found an element which occurs m times (where m is the current maximum number of times any element has occurred). If at the termination point of the algorithm you have more than one element appearing m times, then you know there is no single most-frequently-occurring element.

Comment: I've been trying to do this but I can't really find how to get information I need from the map

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequent operation here is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   // number -> frequency
   map<int, int> idfreq = {{1, 3}, {2, 10}, {3,8}, {9, 15}, {7,30}};
   vector<pair<int, int> > v;
   copy(idfreq.begin(), idfreq.end(), back_inserter(v));
   for (auto& el : v) {
      cout << el.first << " " << el.second << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;
   make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const pair<int,int> &a, const pair<int,int> &b){ return a.second < b.second; });
   // with -std=c++14
   //make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto& a, auto& b){ return a.second < b.second; });
   cout << v.front().first << " " << v.front().second << " most frequent element\n";
   cout << "after make heap call\n";
   for (auto& el : v) {
      cout << el.first << " " << el.second << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```